# How to handle empty data in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/education_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This is my current xml layout file for recycle view.

How to handle empty data in recycler view?
is it possible when put text to display "no data" in same layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I do it:

In XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/empty_text" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/education_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and in the `Activity`:

```
if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                        //if data is available, don't show the empty text
                        emptyText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data); // pass the data to your adapter here
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else
                        emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Thanks Viswesh and Ishata, I follow the instruction and its work.

Comment: You need to observe the dataset in an adapter. if the dataset is empty then only show empty view. This solution will not work if the items are removed dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The new way is to use View Flipper

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_userTaskRecycleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No task found"
                android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
```

and then in the activity check if DataSet is empty or not like:

```
if(dataSet.isEmpty()){
viewFlipper.showNext();
//this will automatically show the next layout in the view flipper.

}
else{
// set your adapter here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `textview` with text "No data available". And in your java put

```
if(noData)
{
  textview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
  recylerView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}else{
  textview.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  recylerView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
```

Comment: where I put the textView in layout ? in same layout or not ? for condition "noData", where I  put that condition ? in adapter or in activity ?

Comment: @AzdaFirmansyah that depends upon how you're fetching the data. I would say when you're fetching the data, if there's no data, make the `TextView` visible. Else, pass the data to the adapter and make the `TextView` invisible/gone.